# Map Text.append over a list but with the arguments from the list first in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, text, functional-programming, text-processing

Basically, I have a list `["apple", "banana"]` and I want to append `"|4"` to each argument in the list, so that I end up with `["apple|4", "banana|4"]`.

I can do `map (Text.append "|4") ["apple", "banana"]`, but that appends in the wrong order, i.e. the result is `["|4apple", "|4banana"]`.

Is there a good way to tell `Text.append` to go in the other direction in this map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. One way is to use [`flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

```hs
map (flip Text.append "|4") ["apple", "banana"]
```

You could also explicitly use a lambda:

```hs
map (\t -> Text.append t "|4") ["apple", "banana"]
```

Or use the backtick infix operator syntax:

```hs
map (`Text.append` "|4") ["apple", "banana"]
```